# FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY isn't set for intents from history

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, kindle-fire

In my activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

I use `onNewIntent` to handle new intents. I don't need to process intents from history and in the beggining I've put this code

```
  if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
    return;
  }
```

However this flag is not set for the history intents on **Kindle Fire**. On other android devices this code works good. Maybe there are any other ways to avoid handling history intents?

Comment: Doesn't seem to show up for me on a couple of 4.0 phones either...

Comment: I am also have this problem according to my google play developer console crash reports

Comment: Sounds like the kindle fire launcher doesn't do all the same things as the android launcher.  Have you tried filing a bug report with amazon?

Answer (score 0):

Kindle dont support all android operations, check at https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/intents-supported.html

Comment: While you might have a point, your link is not relevant to the actual question at issue here, which does not concern the Intents that a device can handle via its default software, but rather the flags attached by the system to Intents delivered to 3rd party apps.