# history applications stack - still with last intent

Tags: android, dialog, message, android-dialog

I have a service that turn on my app sometimes, the  main activity prompt `Dialog` message to user sometimes,
after the user answer YES\NO I call to `finish()` to close the app.

my problem is when the message is shown, user answers it and app was call to `finish()` and when you look in the `recent history` you played before (in samsung for example you press long on home button) you will see my app along with other apps user started.

when you push it to open it again the `Dialog` show again..

How to show the activity when launched from recent app without showing the  `Dialog`

```
public void dialog_1(){
        myDialogViewN = new MyDialogViewNegativeTime(MainActivity.this);

        // Setting vibrator
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        long[] pattern= {100, 1000};
        vibrator.vibrate(  pattern,0   );

        // Setting 2 Dialog Listeners       
        myDialogViewN.setOnDialogListener(new DialogListener()      {           
            @Override
            public void onNegativeClick()
            {           
                // Stopping Vibraror
                if (vibrator.hasVibrator()){
                    vibrator.cancel();
                    vibrator = null;
                }

                initialize_DialogToUser();                  /// ??
                SendDataToService(3);       //doesn't want reminder
                myDialogViewN.dismissDialog();
                waitForDialogAnswer=false;
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositiveClick()
            {
                // Stopping Vibrator
                if (vibrator.hasVibrator()){
                    vibrator.cancel();
                    vibrator = null;
                }

                initialize_DialogToUser();
                SendDataToService(1);       //remind!
                myDialogViewN.dismissDialog();

                squre.setImageResource(R.drawable.triangle_red2);
                waitForDialogAnswer=false;
                finish();
            }       });         
     myDialogViewN.show();
    }
```

> ```
> @Override
> public void onDestroy()
> {
>     super.onDestroy();
>
>     // close/stop running application on background
>     int id= android.os.Process.myPid();
>     android.os.Process.killProcess(id);
> }
> ```

Comment: Do a debug and see: 1- if the "myDialogViewN.dismissDialog()" hide your dialog 2- That the myDialogViewN.show() is not called again on resume the activity

Comment: i was chacked it,the dialog is clearly disapear after user answer (by `myDialogViewN.dismissDialog()`),  but the problem is still. every time i open the app from history-app, the dialog is show again

Comment: it seems that android save this app state *just* if you open it from history. but if you open it generaly by click the icon, it's ok at this openning..

Comment: Ok, you checked the dialogs hides, but the other i told you? I have used dialogs many times and this never happens.

Comment: i chacked the `myDialogViewN.show()` too, and it realy call again.

Comment: There you have, follow the call to dialog_1() after stop (finish) your app and see where and why is calling again if don't have to be

Comment: i chacked the `myDialogViewN.show()` too, and it realy call again. after a search i see that it's different to open your app from history and from the main icon, if you open from history the intent of this activity was not delete!       there is a way to chack it by
 a flag of intent - `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733634/flag-activity-launched-from-history-isnt-set-for-intents-from-history[link]

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866149/android-starting-app-from-recent-applications-starts-it-with-the-last-set-of[link]

Comment: but it's still not work, i didnt success to use this flag , because the flag is everytime != 0 so i still dont know if open from history or not

Answer (score 0):

finally i find solution,
the problem was when you open the app from history - the last intent that comes from service to your activity stay there and not goes, in contrary for openning the app by click it's own icon. (different openning ways).

### ***my solution:***

send 2 `intent`'s from `service` to `activity`,

**the first** - with what you really need.

**the second** - after you receive your answer in the service. ***in the second you will not put any data!*** it is a mere intent that comes to change the "stuck" intent in history-app open way.

maby it is stupid, but it's the only solution i found :)